# Find earliest package version with function X

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

So I'm sitting here wondering why the hell I can't find the function I'm looking for, and it turns out it doesn't exist in the version of the package I have installed.

So how do I make Hackage tell me what version that function was added in?

(In particular, so I can specify the correct package bounds in my Cabal description.)

Comment: Did you read https://wiki.haskell.org/Package_versioning_policy ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I did. How does that help me to know which of several dozen versions added the function I want?

Comment: So to be clear, you want to get the minimal version of a library containing a specific function with a given signature?

Comment: I find Luite’s git repositories created from hackage very useful, e.g.: http://hdiff.luite.com/cgit/lens/. You can probably solve your problem by cloning the corresponding repo and applying some git-foo (`git blame`, `git log -G`).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yep, that's what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

[hackage-diff](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hackage-diff) is probably the tool you are looking for.

N.B. I never tried it myself.

Comment: That's a nice find... though I have to say, that tool looks a bit brute-force-ish seeing as it has to invoke `cabal` on temporary directories.

Comment: Obviously it's not perfect, but that's the only partial approach I'm aware of. Best would be maintainers adding *Since x.y.z* annotations to new exports.

Comment: I'm not sure... I'd rather just browse [the git repo](http://hdiff.luite.com/cgit/) to find a particular change. With `hackage-diff` you basically need to manually bisect for that purpose, and when it always needs to completely build the package that ain't too nice.

Comment: Ah, I thought it fetches [hoogle dbs from hackage](https://wiki.haskell.org/Hoogle#Installing_databases_from_Hackage)